# Using pygsheets and searching for specific data and getting result, need output to include the cell location

Tags: list, location, cell, pygsheets

Am working on inventory and, after searching for and locating a product by Mfg. Code, I need an output that prints the row data and location.  No problem in getting the row data but don't know how to have both the data and locating output together.

Comment: Using pygsheets to do search.

Comment: Hi Larry, please post the code that you're using: see [mcve]